# One Custom UITableViewCell in different UITableView of two UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My problem is like this

1. I have one custom `UITableView` cell class with xib file.
2. In Interface builder, I have set its File's Owner as VC1. (subclass of
   `UIViewController` having one `UITableView`)
3. Everything is good till now. `UITableView` shows data in VC1.
4. Now I want to use same customCell in a `UITableView` of VC2.
5. At this stag, what should I set in File's Owner of my cell? VC1, or VC2?

Hope I clear the situation.

Comment: Are you actually connecting anything to File's Owner in Interface Builder?  Do VC1 and VC2 inherit from a common class that you could use as the File's Owner?

Comment: I inherit my every VC to a ParentVC, just to put all common items in all VCs there. Yes my VC1 and VC2 are inherit with ParentVC, which is inherited with UIViewController.

Comment: You could probably set the File's Owner to the ParentVC, then.

Comment: @Isaac: Yes it worked. What I did more, I had to keep same name of custom cell variable in both VCs. It was required because I have to link the IBOutlet of custom cell in its xib file.

Comment: It was our luck that I'm habitual of creating Parent class for every group of classes. What if we don't have parent VC, then is there work around for such situation? Because most of the people direct inherit their VCs with UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should define a view controller class that inherits from your ParentVC and from which VC1 and VC2 (and any other view controllers that will use the particular custom cell XIB) inherit, so that you can define the outlets and whatnot that you want to use in this new view controller class and use this new view controller class as the File's Owner in the XIB.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` from the `UITableView` class?

This method lets you register a cell from a seperate xib. You could register the same cell in multiple tableViews.

Example:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithName:@"CustomCell.xib" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
```

Now you can use the custom cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` with the reuse identifier specified above.

Comment: So in that case, File's Owner of CustomCell will not be significant? Or do we really net to set it?

Comment: That depends. You can have a custom cell class where you have IBOutlets to your custom views inside the cell. Then you'd set the File's Owner in the CustomCell.xib to the subclass of UITableViewCell. Otherwise, if you don't need to reference an views inside the cell you don't have to do anything else. It will just work.